# Accuracy from approximating $\zeta(2)$ with a partial sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

This is for an introductory numerical analysis class. The answer shouldn't be too complicated, but if you have one, feel free to post it.

Figure out what $n$ should be such that
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty {1\over k^2}<10^{-8}.$$

---

**My Simple Algebraic Attempt**

We know that

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty {1\over k^2} = \sum_{k=1}^n {1\over k^2} + \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty {1 \over k^2} \implies \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty {1 \over k^2} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty {1\over k^2} - \sum_{k=1}^n {1\over k^2}$$

And

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty {1\over k^2} = \zeta(2)={\pi^2 \over6}$$

So,

$$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty {1 \over k^2} = {\pi^2 \over6} - \sum_{k=1}^n {1\over k^2}$$

Then,

$$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty {1 \over k^2} < 10^{-8} \implies {\pi^2 \over6} - \sum_{k=1}^n {1\over k^2} < 10^{-8} \implies \sum_{k=1}^n {1\over k^2} > {\pi^2 \over6} - 10^{-8}$$

I'm currently trying to brute force an answer to the last expression, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is there any additional information to the question? In particular, is it sufficient to find any $n$ such that the inequality holds, or must we find the minimal $n$ ?

Comment: Hm, it doesn't say to find a minimal $n$. The assignment doesn't give much more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\displaystyle \frac{1}{k^2} < \frac{1}{(k-1)k } = \frac{1}{k-1} - \frac{1}{k}$ we can bound your term by a telescoping sum: $$\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} < \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} \right)+\left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+2} \right)+\left(\frac{1}{n+2} - \frac{1}{n+3} \right) + \cdots = \frac{1}{n}$$ so $n=10^8$ works. The estimate we used isn't too weak, and this $n$ shouldn't be much worse than the minimal $n.$

Comment: Hm, sure. I also tried bounding it by an integral and got $n=10^8$.

Comment: I was going to use this method, but I was too slow. :-)

Comment: @robjohn I was going to add the integral method in an edit, but I was too slow as well!

Comment: Actually, I think you can bound the difference between this approximation and the real answer by $\frac{1}{n^2}$ which would make the minimal $n$ $10^8-1$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**
$$
\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\le\int_n^\infty\frac1{x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\frac1n
$$

Comment: This is what I initially tried, but I wasn't sure about it. Thanks for verifying!

Comment: $\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac1{k^2} \ge \int_{n+1}^\infty\frac1{x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{n+1}$ so you can bound from both sides

Comment: @Henry: nice. Add that to your answer and undelete it :-)

Answer (score 2):

A simple idea is to replace the remainder of the series by the corresponding integral :
$$\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac 1{k^2}\sim \int_{N+1}^\infty \frac {dk}{k^2}$$
or get the inequality :
$$\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac 1{k^2}<  \int_N^\infty \frac {dk}{k^2}=\frac 1N$$

If you wish more precision you may use [Euler Maclaurin formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) and get (for $x=2$ in your case) :
$$\zeta(x)-\sum_{k=1}^N \frac 1{k^x} \sim   
               \frac 1{(x-1)N^{x-1}}-\frac 1{2\,N^x}
               + \frac x{12\,N^{x+1}}
               - \frac {x\,(x+1)(x+2)}{720\,N^{x+3}}
               +\frac {x\,(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)}{30240\,N^{x+5}}
               +...$$
(the constants $\ \frac 1{2},\ \frac 1{12},\ \frac 1{720}$ are $\frac {|B_n|}{n!}$ with $B_n$ a [Bernoulli number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number))

This is an asymptotic expansion and the error made corresponds to the first term omitted.

Comment: For the exponent $2$, I did this very thing in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/174393).

Comment: @robjohn: I like this method (much simpler to implement than Riemann-Siegel and with a much more direct error term) and the numerical details that you showed in your answer (+1: I fear I missed that thread...). This formula has the interesting feature of becoming exact for negative integer $x$ (only the first terms are not $0$).

Comment: Yes, because the EMS formula terminates for polynomials. More generally, I showed in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/156085) that if the Fourier transform of a function is supported within $[-1,1]$, then the EMS formula converges for that function.