# Why is $\lim_{x\to 1}\sqrt{1-x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^2}=\sqrt{\pi}/2\,\,$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

It is well-known that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=1/(1-x)$. However, it seems difficult to find $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^2}$. A natural problem is study its behavior around $1$. A problem states that
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\sqrt{1-x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^2}=\sqrt{\pi}/2.$$

How can we prove this? Abel summation formula? Any others? I have no idea.

Comment: "Limit with series" is a useless title.

Comment: The key term here is Jacobi Theta Function

Comment: If you write $x=e^{-\pi t}=e^{i\pi\tau}$ with $\tau=it$, then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n^2}$ is closely related to a Jacobi theta function, which has a nice functional equation.

Comment: @AlexR.: I have expanded your hint into an answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What about squaring? We have
$$ \left(\sum_{n\geq 0}x^{n^2}\right)^{2} = \sum_{n\geq 0}r_2(n)\,x^n $$
where
$$ r_2(n) = \left|\left\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{N}^2: a^2+b^2 = n\right\}\right| $$
is [a nice arithmetic function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html). For instance, $\sum_{n=0}^{N}r_2(n)$ is the number of lattice points with non-negative coordinates inside the circle $x^2+y^2=N$, but also the coefficient of $x^N$ in
$$ \frac{1}{1-x}\left(\sum_{n\geq 0}x^{n^2}\right)^{2} = \sum_{N\geq 0}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{N}r_2(n)\right) x^N. $$
By [Gauss circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem) with Voronoi bound we have that $\sum_{n=0}^{N}r_2(n)=\frac{\pi N}{4}+O(N^{1/3})$, hence $x=1$ is a double pole of the previous function and the first term of its Laurent expansion around $x=1$ is given by $\frac{\pi}{4(1-x)^2}$. By multiplying by $(1-x)^2$ and taking the limit as $x\to 1^-$ we get:
$$ \lim_{x\to 1^-}\,(1-x)\left(\sum_{n\geq 0}x^{n^2}\right)^2 = \frac{\pi}{4} $$
and the claim easily follows.
It is interesting to point out that the same approach shows that, for any $k\geq 2$,
$$ \lim_{x\to 1^-}(1-x)\left(\sum_{n\geq 0}x^{n^k}\right)^k $$
is exactly the (hyper-)volume enclosed by $x_1\geq 0,x_2\geq 0,\ldots x_k\geq 0$ and $x_1^k+x_2^k+\ldots+x_k^k = 1$, that can be computed in the following way: if we assume that $X_1,\ldots,X_k$ are i.i.d. random variables with uniform distribution over $(0,1)$, the PDF of $X_i$ is supported on $(0,1)$ and given by $f(t)=\frac{1}{k} t^{1/k-1}$. To compute the previous volume, it is enough to compute the characteristic function of $X_i$, take its $k$-th power, consider the inverse Fourier transform and integrate it over $(0,1)$ to get the probability that $X_1^k+\ldots+X_k^k\leq 1.$

Comment: You posted very good answers to most questions here. I wonder if you will get a PhD in math in your home country any time soon?

Comment: @DeepSea: my personal and work life is quite troubled at the moment. I left my PhD in order to take part at the last abilitation procedure for high-school teachers, but I did not pass the test. Are you going to ask *how is that possible*? Well, I haven't the slighest clue, but I live in Italy, and sadly used to the idea that everything is quite "random" (just to be polite) here.

Comment: Nice answer (+1), i'm sorry to hear about your situation you're a very gifted mathematician in my eyes!

Comment: @DeepSea: what if someone has published papers but is not a univ professor, just like me? Is that enough to call me a pro?  *Mathematician* is just a word, and language does not meet the same rigor criteria as mathematics, so I think the actual difference stays in the eye of the beholder, more than anywhere else.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: You are very close to obtaining that title. What you should have done instead is to attend a university in the U.S, and completed a doctoral program and colaborate with other mathematicians in your field to release some papers, then you are all set. In my opinion, a professional mathematician knows some advanced areas such as: category theory, set theory well enough to incorporate those ideas into their work, and they know topology, and algebraic geometry as well. So it seems there is a whole set of skills and knowledge to be acquired during the PhD program.

Comment: You seem to have quite a U.S-centric view of the world. For someone born far enough (say in another continent) it is not so painless to move his whole life elsewhere. And I am pretty confident we may practice very advanced mathematics also without category theory or algebraic geometry. Would you call Erdos a professional mathematician, by your standards? :/

Comment: I personally do not like to be told what I have to do, thank you. And anyway, what do you mean by *recreational math*? It does not look to me that I am solving sudokus...

Comment: I would give a heartfelt feedback to you that all of your answers point me to thinking you enjoy old school math Olympiad style problems. Its fine, but it won't lead you to becoming a pro-mathematician as you would want to because it is only half of the skills required to be one mathematician, the other half lies in advanced areas.

Answer (score 3):

by the [Mac-Laurin-Cauchy Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) formula,
($S(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{\log(x)n^2}$)  we have for $x<1$ 
$$
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{-\log(x)}}=\int_0^{\infty}e^{\log(x)n^2}dn\leq \\S(x)=\\ \leq 1+ \int_0^{\infty}e^{\log(x)n^2}dn=1+\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{-\log(x)}}
$$

Expanding around $x=1_-$

$$
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{1-x}} \leq S(x)\leq 1+\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{1-x}}
$$

and therefore

> $$
> \lim_{x\rightarrow1_-}\sqrt{1-x}S(x)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}
> $$

Comment: This does not look like an application of Euler-Maclaurin. Euler-Maclaurin would give an asymptotic approximation of a finite sum of a series. Each approximation would involve a different constant dependent on the value of $x$. This approximation works because the integral approximates the sum, not because of Euler-Maclaurin.

Comment: @robjohn thanks for the feedback, i will review this answer on the weekend. from my understanding 'til now is was pretty sure that i can apply EM also to infinite sums, but i will check...

Comment: It can be used to numerically evaluate a series, but there is a constant of integration that usually prevents one from using the EMSF by itself from finding the exact value of an infinite series. It is the constant of integration that is usually sought when evaluating infinite series with EMSF. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174393) is one of mine that shows how this is done.

Comment: @robjohn regardless that i am still not sure if Euler-MacLaurin is applicable here, i changed the answer in a way that it employs the integral test for series so that it is definitly correct

Answer (score 2):

We can use also the Abel's summation formula. We have $$S\left(N\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{N}x^{n^{2}}=\left(N+1\right)x^{N^{2}}-2\log\left(x\right)\int_{0}^{N}\left\lfloor t+1\right\rfloor tx^{t^{2}}dt
 $$ where $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor 
 $ is the floor function. Since $t-1\leq\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor \leq t
 $ we have $$ \left(N+1\right)x^{N^{2}}-2\log\left(x\right)\int_{0}^{N}t^{2}x^{t^{2}}dt\leq S\left(N\right)\leq Nx^{N^{2}}-2\log\left(x\right)\int_{0}^{N}t^{2}x^{t^{2}}dt+1.
 $$ Now let us consider the integral. We have, integrating by parts, $$2\log\left(x\right)\int_{0}^{N}t^{2}x^{t^{2}}=x^{N^{2}}N-\int_{0}^{N}x^{t^{2}}dt=x^{N^{2}}N-\int_{0}^{N}e^{\log\left(x\right)t^{2}}dt
 $$ $$=x^{N^{2}}N-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\textrm{erfi}\left(iN\sqrt{-\log\left(x\right)}\right)}{2i\sqrt{-\log\left(x\right)}}\rightarrow\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{-\log\left(x\right)}}
 $$ as $N\rightarrow\infty
 $, where $\textrm{erfi}\left(x\right)
 $ is the [imaginary error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html). So using the expansion of $\log$ at $x=1$ and the squeeze theorem we can conclude.

Answer (score 2):

We will use variable $q$ instead of $x$ so that we can visibly link the problem to theta functions. We have $$\vartheta_{3}(q) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}q^{n^{2}} = \sqrt{\frac{2K}{\pi}}$$ where $K$ is the elliptic integral of first kind and $q = e^{-\pi K'/K}$. Now we can see that $$\sqrt{1 - q}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}q^{n^{2}} = \sqrt{1 - q}\cdot\frac{\vartheta_{3}(q) + 1}{2}$$ and then clearly $$\lim_{q \to 1^{-}}\sqrt{1 - q}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}q^{n^{2}} = \frac{1}{2}\lim_{q \to 1^{-}}\sqrt{1 - q}\vartheta_{3}(q) = \frac{1}{2}\lim_{q \to 1^{-}}\sqrt{\frac{2K(1 - q)}{\pi}}$$ and from $q = e^{-\pi K'/K}$ we can see that the limit is equal to $$\frac{1}{2}\lim_{k \to 1^{-}}\sqrt{2K'}$$ which is $$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}$$ Here we have used the fact that as $q \to 1^{-}$ we have modulus $k \to 1^{-}$ so that $K' \to \pi/2$ and $K \to \infty$ and hence from $q = e^{-\pi K'/K}$ we get $$1 - q = \pi\frac{K'}{K} + o(1/K)$$ A more elementary answer by G. H. Hardy is [available here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/817889/72031).

Comment: You already marked it as a $\underline{duplicate}$.