# What is $\lim_{x\to1^{-}} (1-x)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^{i^2}\right)^{2}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, power-series

This is the problem I was presented with:
$$\text{Given } f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^{i^2} ,$$
$$\text{find } \lim_{x\to1^{-}} (1-x)f(x)^2 .$$
At first, I tried figuring out a generating function for $f(x)$, squaring it, and multiplying it by $(1-x)$. I then learned that $f(x)$ does not have a traditional generating function connected to it. I then tried dividing $f(x)^2$ by $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+\cdots)$, the expanded form of $\frac{1}{1-x}$. I couldn't figure out how to make that work out either. Is there some way I should simplify $f(x)$ to make this an easier limit to solve?

Comment: What do you mean "figure out" a generating function for $f$. It is defined by a generating function. $f(x)^2=\sum a_nx^n$ where $a_n$ is the number of ways to write $n$ as the sum of of two squares.  But I don't see that knowledge being much help.

Comment: I more meant that I was trying to figure out a simpler form of the series. (Like how, as I said, $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-x}$). I found that $f(x) = \frac{\vartheta_3(0, x) + 1}{2}$ where $\vartheta_a(x,q)$ is the Jacobi theta function. I could not figure out how to use this fact to my advantage.

Comment: See this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/817889/72031

Comment: the euler mac laurin formula gives you another pretty handy way to calculate the limit in question :)

Comment: @tired: how do you apply Euler-Maclaurin to this series?

Comment: @robjohn heuristically io would just "square" my answer here: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1887632/why-is-lim-x-to-1-sqrt1-x-sum-n-0-infty-xn2-sqrt-pi-2/1887644#1887644

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe to have already solved this question, but I am not managing to find the duplicate, so I will re-sketch my argument. By squaring $f(x)$ we get
$$ f(x)^2 = \sum_{n\geq 0} \widetilde{r}_2(n) x^n $$
where
$$ r_n(n)=\left|\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}^2: a^2+b^2=n\}\right|,\qquad \widetilde{r}_n(n)=\left|\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{N}^2: a^2+b^2=n\}\right|$$
and by [Gauss circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem)
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{N}r_2(n) = \pi N + O(\sqrt{N}) $$
(the error term can be improved into $O(N^{1/3})$ by Voronoi summation formula, but the previous elementary bound is sufficient for our purposes), such that
$$ R(N) = \sum_{n=0}^{N}\widetilde{r}_2(n) = \frac{\pi}{4}N +O(\sqrt{N}) $$
and
$$ \frac{f(x)^2}{1-x} = \sum_{N\geq 0} R(N) x^N = \frac{\frac{\pi}{4}x}{(1-x)^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^{3/2}}\right)$$
as $x\to 1^-$. Multiplying both sides by $(1-x)^2$ and considering the limit as $x\to 1^-$ we get:
$$ \lim_{x\to 1^-}(1-x)f(x)^2 = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{4}}. $$

---

An alternative approach comes from considering the convolution with an approximate identity.
In general
$$ \left(\sum_{n\geq 0} x^{n^k}\right)^k \sim \frac{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k}{1-x} $$
as $x\to 1^-$. Oh, now I have found [the answer I was mentioning before](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1887644/44121), containing a (sketch of) proof of the last statement, too.

Comment: +1 for the generalization at the end.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I believe the same asymptotic can be found in Hardy's earliest works on the Waring's problem.

Comment: Nice work (+1).

Answer (score 7):

Let me check my luck with that ...

$$\lim_{x\to 1^{-}} (1-x)f^2(x)=\lim_{a\to -1} \lim_{x\to 1^{-}} (1-x)\left(\int_0^{\infty} x^{-a t^2}\textrm{d}t\right)^2=\lim_{a\to -1} \lim_{x\to 1^{-}}\frac{\pi}{4a}\frac{1-x}{\log(x)}=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$

The problem can be extended in more ways. One example is

$$\lim_{x\to 1^{-}} (1-x)g^3(x)=\lim_{x\to 1^{-}} (1-x)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^{i^3}\right)^3=\frac{1}{27}\left(\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\right)^3,$$
where the method described above works perfectly.

So, in the generalized form,

$$\lim_{x\to 1^{-}} (1-x)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^{i^n}\right)^n=\frac{1}{n^n}\left(\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^n.$$

When letting to $n \to \infty$, 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \lim_{x\to 1^{-}} (1-x)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^{i^n}\right)^n=\frac{1}{e^{\gamma}}.$$

Comment: (+1) Writing this as $\Gamma\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ and noting that $\Gamma(1)=1$ and $\Gamma'(1)=-\gamma$, gives your final limit.

Comment: Since I'm not particularly experienced, I do not understand how you could substitute an integral for the sum. Is this part of a theorem I have not heard of before?

Comment: @KirkFox Read George Pólya.

Answer (score 4):

Since $x^{t^k}=e^{-\log(1/x)\,t^k}$, we have for $x\lt1$,
$$
x^{(n+1)^k}
\le\int_n^{n+1}e^{-\log(1/x)\,t^k}\,\mathrm{d}t
\le x^{n^k}\tag1
$$
Summing in $n$ yields
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n^k}\le\int_0^\infty e^{-\log(1/x)\,t^k}\,\mathrm{d}t\le\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^k}\tag2
$$
multiplying by $\log(1/x)^{1/k}$ gives
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-t^k}\mathrm{d}t\le\log(1/x)^{1/k}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^k}\le\log(1/x)^{1/k}+\int_0^\infty e^{-t^k}\mathrm{d}t\tag3
$$
Since
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\log(1/x)}{1-x}=1\tag4
$$
the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) and $(3)$ say that
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to1^-}(1-x)^{1/k}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^k}
&=\lim_{x\to1^-}\log(1/x)^{1/k}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^k}\\
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-t^k}\mathrm{d}t\\[3pt]
&=\frac1k\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{\frac1k-1}\mathrm{d}t\\[3pt]
&=\frac1k\Gamma\!\left(\frac1k\right)\\[6pt]
&=\Gamma\!\left(1+\frac1k\right)\tag5
\end{align}
$$
That is,
$$
\lim_{x\to1^-}(1-x)\,\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^k}\right)^k=\Gamma\left(1+\frac1k\right)^k\tag6
$$

---

For $k=2$, $(6)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to1^-}(1-x)\,\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^2}\right)^2
&=\Gamma\left(\frac32\right)^2\\
&=\frac\pi4\tag7
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Riemann sums in the unexpected places! (+1)

Comment: @Waiting: I have changed the Riemann Sum approach to a Squeeze Theorem approach, which is the same for a bounded, decreasing function anyway.

Comment: That's the way to go!:-)

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\lim_{x \to 1^{\large -}}\bracks{\pars{1 - x}
\pars{\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}x^{i^{\large 2}}}^{2}}} =
\lim_{x \to 0^{\large +}}\braces{x
\bracks{\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}\pars{1 - x}^{i^{\large 2}}}^{2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{x \to 0^{\large +}}\braces{x
\bracks{\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{i^{2}\ln\pars{1 - x}}}^{2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{x \to 0^{\large +}}\braces{x
\bracks{\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-x\,i^{2}}\,\dd i}^{2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{x \to 0^{\large +}}\bracks{x
\pars{{1 \over 2}\root{\pi \over x}}^{2}} =
\bbx{\pi \over 4}
\end{align}

> See $\ds{\quad\underline{\textsf{Laplace Method for Sums}}\quad }$ in
>   [Analytic Combinatorics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521898064) by Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick, Cambridge University Press $2009$.

Answer (score 2):

Not that elementary, but... It is well known that for $x > 0$
$$\theta(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2 x^2} = \frac{1}{x}\theta\big(\frac{1}{x}\big)$$
(this is usually proven using Poisson summation formula).

As $f(x) = \displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \theta\left(\sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\pi}\ln\displaystyle\frac{1}{x}}\right)\right)$, the limit is easily seen to be $\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your answer? I am genuinely interested.

Comment: @JackyChong: just apply the [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula) to $f(e^{-z})=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{-n^2 z}\right).$